Expo Camera saving video using createAssetAsync not working on iOS only. ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ASSET_TYPE for .mov file
I am using Expo in React Native, and I want the user to record videos using the camera and save it to the phone. Everything is working fine on Android but on iOS, the createAssetAsync call is failing with the following error:
Error: This URL does not contain a valid asset type: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/22FC2F8C-E052-4FF5-B451-4973C95AD74E/Library/Caches/Camera/50220C17-AB3B-4586-80D7-67A6D27D6105.mov
And also  {"code": "ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ASSET_TYPE"}
Here is my useEffect code that saves the video:
    useEffect(() => {

        const saveVideo = async () => {
            console.log('rURI:', recordedUri);
            console.log('recordedUri type:', typeof recordedUri);
            if (recordedUri) {

                // Check file existence
                const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(recordedUri);
                console.log('fileInfo:', fileInfo);
                if (!fileInfo.exists) {
                    console.error('File does not exist:', recordedUri);
                    return;
                }

                const { status, canAskAgain } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
                if (status !== 'granted' && canAskAgain) {
                    const fullPermission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync({ writeOnly: false });
                    console.log('Full permission status:', fullPermission.status);
                }


                try{
                const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(recordedUri);
                console.log('asset:', asset);
                setNewAssetCounter(newAssetCounter + 1);}
                catch (err) {
                    console.log('Error creating asset:', JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
                }
            }
            closeCamera();
        }
        saveVideo();
    },
    [recordedUri])

Here is my code where I record the video:
    const startRecording = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
        setVideoElapsedTime(0);
        const videoRecordPromise = cameraRef.current.recordAsync();
        if (videoRecordPromise) {
            setIsRecording(true);
            timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
                setVideoElapsedTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);
            }, 1000);
            const video = await videoRecordPromise;
            setRecordedUri(video.uri);
        }
    }
};

// Stop recording
const stopRecording = async () => {

    const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
    console.log('status:', status);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Permission to access media library is required!');
        return;
    }

    console.log('line157');
    try {
        if (cameraRef.current && isRecording) {
            console.log('line159');
            cameraRef.current.stopRecording();
            setIsRecording(false);
            clearInterval(timerRef.current);
            console.log('line162');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving video:', error);
    }
};

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

On iOS, recordAsync accepts a codec option which on my iPhone accepts values of "hvc1", "avc1", "jpeg". However the first two options are still giving me the error of unsupported asset type. The return value of recordAsync is supposed to contain a codec property in addition to uri but for me it only has uri and no codec.

I tried replacing Expo Camera with Expo ImagePicker and the same issue occurs even then. The result from the video recording is a valid object with valid uri, non zero file size, exists:true. But createAssetAsync is failing with the error ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ASSET_TYPE
